# Inner Join user tables to select users with roles

Tags: sql, join-tables

I am trying to view a list of users (who are music *artists*) with the following function.

```
function show_authors($ltr) {
    global $wpdb;
    $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->users.* FROM $wpdb->users WHERE $wpdb->users.display_name LIKE '$ltr%' ORDER BY $wpdb->users.display_name";

/**
    $querystr = "
    SELECT      *
    FROM        $wpdb->users
    INNER JOIN  $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value
                ON $wpdb->users.user_id = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id
                AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
                AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = %artist%
    WHERE       $wpdb->users.display_name LIKE '$ltr%' 
            AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' 
                    AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%artist%'
    ORDER BY    $wpdb->users.display_name ASC
    ";
**/

    $users = $wpdb->get_col($querystr);
    echo "<ul style=\"list-style-type: none;\">";
        foreach($users as $user) {
          $user = get_userdata($user);
          $post_count = get_usernumposts($user->ID);
           echo '<li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <a href="' . get_author_posts_url($user->ID, $user->user_nicename) . '"> ' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name . '</a> ('. $post_count .' songs)</li>';
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

I tried `inner join` the *usermeta* table so that I can select the necessary users with the `meta_key` named *wp_capabilities* which has the name of the user role in the `meta_value` field.

The shown code works fine. When I try to use the commented out query, the result is empty. What I might be doing wrong? Or is there any efficient or better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

### The Problems

You risk SQL injection, with your current setup:

```
$wpdb->users.display_name LIKE '$ltr%'
```

The following could also be a problematic part in your SQL query:

```
AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value = %artist%
```

i.e. using `=` instead of `LIKE`.

You're also missing the quotes: `%\"artist\"%`, to exclude e.g. `bartist` or `fartist` ;-)

But you don't need to construct this SQL query by hand.

### Better Alternatives

You could use the [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) class:

```
$users = new WP_User_Query( [ 'role' => 'artist' ] );
```

or it's [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) wrapper instead:

```
$users = get_users( [ 'role' => 'artist' ] );
```

It will generate the SQL query for you, with the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: *fartist*, well, that is hillarious, hahahaha. Just imagine....

Comment: ps: I had this amazingly talented guy in mind that's  mentioned in  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A9tomane)  ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: If I wet my pants today, it will be all on you. This made the Monday more bareably ;-)